# Monotouch - Changing size and position of table view

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I recently got into iPhone development and love it. I have, however, been struggling with table views for the past couple of hours, more specifically giving the table view a custom height and adding a navigation bar above it.

In the interface builder, I dragged a Table View and Navigation Bar onto the "screen" of the iPhone. I then wired them up as outlets.

MainScreen.h from xib file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MainScreen : UIViewController 
{
    UINavigationBar *_nbMainScreen;
    UITableView *_tblMainScreen;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *nbMainScreen;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tblMainScreen;

@end
```

I created a separate C# class for the table data.

GenericTable.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace TestProject
{
    public class GenericTable : UITableViewSource
    {
        protected string[] tableItems;
        protected string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";

        public GenericTable (string[] items)
        {
            tableItems = items;
        }


        public override int NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
        {
            return 1;
        }


        public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
        {
            return tableItems.Length;
        }

        public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            new UIAlertView("Row Selected"
                    , tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK", null).Show();
            tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
        }


        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
            string item = tableItems[indexPath.Row];

            //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
        { 
                     cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier); }

                 cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

                 return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

MainScreen.cs  :

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace TestProject
{
public partial class MainScreen : UIViewController
{
    static bool UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone {
        get { return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone; }
    }

    public MainScreen ()
        : base (UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone ? "MainScreen_iPhone" : "MainScreen_iPad", null)
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        tblMainScreen = new UITableView(View.Bounds);
        tblMainScreen.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
        CreateTableItems();
        Add (tblMainScreen);




        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    protected void CreateTableItems ()
    {
        List<string> tableItems = new List<string> ();
        tableItems.Add ("Dog");
        tableItems.Add ("Cat");
        tableItems.Add ("Plane");
        tableItems.Add ("Phone");
        tableItems.Add ("Baloon");
        tblMainScreen.Source = new GenericTable(tableItems.ToArray());
    }
}
```

}

This is a common strategy I found in multiple forums and tutorial sites, but all of them involve a fullscreen table view. As of right now my table is populated correctly, but, like in the forum posts, it takes up the entire screen. Even if I change the size/position of the table in the IB, it still remains in full screen, and the Navigation Bar doesn't appear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Interface Builder, Modify the TopBar property..
when your UIViewController is selected.

It should be on that panel with the little "Shield-like" emblem.

After that, modify your AppDelegate file to something like the code I've listed below :

[image]

```
        MainScreen controller;
        UINavigationController navcontroller;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {

            // create a new window instance based on the screen size
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            controller = new MainScreen ();

            var initialControllers = new List<UIViewController>();
            initialControllers.Add (controller);

            navcontroller = new UINavigationController ();
            navcontroller.ViewControllers = initialControllers.ToArray ();
            window.RootViewController = navcontroller;
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
            return true;
        }
```